# Do SPARQL queries on :BaseKB

Tags: sparql, freebase, virtuoso

I have loaded :BaseKB Lite in Virtuoso (Windows).

What SPARQL statement should I use in Vitruoso SPARQL endpoint(http:/comphost:8890/sparql) to get all topics names with all their aliases related to the Freebase 'Sports' domain (in English) except Person?

In Freebase there is a '/sports' topic with all sub-topics like'/sports/sports_league_season'.
I can't found how it maps to BaseKB schema so far((

Results example:

```
 .......

 Manchester United F.C.|Manchester United FC|The Red Devils|Manch Untd|Manchester United Football Club
 London 2012|London 2012 Olympic Games| XXX Olympic games

 ........
```

Note: no athletes exist in this list (no Maria Sharapova, Victoria Azarenka etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SPARQL returns all aliases for "Manchester United F.C"

```
     prefix basekb: <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
     prefix public: <http://rdf.basekb.com/public/>
     prefix fbase: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
     prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
     prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
     prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
      select ?label ?alias{
                 basekb:m.050fh <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/m.01gr> ?alias ; 
                                                       rdfs:label ?label.
      filter(lang(?label) = 'en').
      } limit 100

    Output:
      label     alias
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "United"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "Manchester United"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "Red Devils"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "The Red Devils"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "Manchester United Football Club"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "Manchester United FC"@en
      "Manchester United F.C."@en   "Man United"@en
```